# Reloading issue using navlink

Tags: reactjs, routes

I have react application which is changing routes(using navlink) and working fine.But when I manually reload it and then I click on those navlink it relaods every time

This is app.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
<Routes>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route><Route path="/" element={<HomeLayout />} >
  <Route path="/Dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="/ManageContent" element=(<ManageContent />}
</Route>
```

This is homelayout.js

```
<ul>
    <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink to="/Dashboard" activeClassName="active" className="nav-link">
            <span className="pcoded-micon"> <i className="feather icon-home"></i></span>
            <span className="pcoded-mtext">Dashboard</span>
        </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li className="nav-item">
        <NavLink to="/ManageContent" activeClassName="active" className="nav-link" <span className="pcoded-micon">
            <i className="feather icon-users"></i>
            <span className="pcoded-mtext">Manage Content</span>
        </NavLink>
    </li>
</ul>
```